# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory exception

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

i am executing simple Dependency Injection program of spring & getting this exception. 
I have already included common-logging1.1.1.jar and spring.jar file. Could you please help to out?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:56)
    at com.client.StoryReader.main(StoryReader.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: First, double check that your classpath is indeed correct.

Second, try opening the jar and check that it actually contains the org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory class.

Finally, try debugging by setting a breakpoint in the class loader.

Comment: All the answers below suggesting ```commons-logging``` is a step backwards. Use ```jcl-over-slf4j``` instead.

Comment: In Android add testCompile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1' to app.gradle

Answer (score 141):

If you're using maven for managing dependencies, add the following lines in your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 124):

I have also faced the same issues, to fix, download the jar files from the below url

http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

and copy to your lib folder, will resolve your issue.

Comment: this doesn't work for me ,even after adding above mentioned commons jar in classpath

Comment: Neither for me. These libs are broken. It's so frustating.

Answer (score 43):

You just download [commons-logging-1.1.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.2/commons-logging-1.1.2.jar) and then copy this file in to libs

finally, it works.

Answer (score 26):

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar or jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar al

If you are using maven, use the below code.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Including "jcl-over-slf4j" was the only solution that works for me. I already had the commons-logging in my dependencies.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot version 2.0.1.RELEASE  with maven. This was the only solution that worked for me too.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, and solved it by just adding the `commons-logging.jar` to the class path.

Answer (score 9):

Setting the scope to compile did it for me

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Solved my situation. When running Mockito test cases, I got this error and having this dependency in pom.xml solved.

Answer (score 8):

Adding commons-logging.jar or commons-logging-1.1.jar will solve this...

Answer (score 6):

> I have already included common-logging1.1.1.jar and ...

Are you sure you spelled the name of the JAR file exactly right? I think it should probably be `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` (note the extra `-` in the name). Also check if the directory name is correct.

`NoClassDefFoundError` always means that a class cannot be found, so most likely your class path is not correct.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` can also be caused by other corner cases, like when class initializers fail in obscure circumstances.

Comment: Furthermore, if he gets a NoClassDefFoundError because the class instantiation failed, then he should have gotten a ExceptionInInitializerError exception first (unless of course it was caught silently).

Comment: And don't forget the "s" `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`

Answer (score 5):

Try doing a complete clean of the target/deployment directory for the app to get rid of any stale library jars. Make a fresh build and check that commons-logging.jar is actually being placed in the correct lib folder. It might not be included when you are building the library for the application.

Answer (score 4):

Issue solved by adding commons-logging.jar

Imp files are ,

```
antlr-runtime-3.0.1

org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2

org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2

commons-logging-1.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Two options (at least):

1. Add the commons-logging jar to your file by copying it into a local folder.

Note: linking the jar can lead to problems with the server and maybe the reason why it's added to the build path but not solving the server startup problem.

So don't point the jar to an external folder.

OR...

2. If you really don't want to add it locally because you're sharing the jar between projects, then...

If you're using a tc server instance, then you need to add the jar as an external jar to the server instance run configurations.

go to run as, run configurations..., {your tc server instance}, and then the Class Path tab.

Then add the commons-logging jar.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same trouble than you.
Finally I checked the version of apache possessing the class. 
I found that the version 1.0.4 has the class.

Try to use the version 1.0.4 instead of 1.1.X or 1.2.X

My dependencies :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-client-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My Java Code

```
J4pClient j4pClient = new J4pClient("http://localhost:8080/jolokia");
J4pReadRequest req = new J4pReadRequest("java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage");
req.setPath("used");
J4pReadResponse resp = j4pClient.execute(req);
System.out.println(resp.getValue());
```

My Result :

```
130489168
```

Double check also that your maven dependencies are well imported.

Answer (score 3):

The topic is very outdated. But it still can be met ourdays.

`commons-logging`, or also known as `jcl` is a deprecated library. [The last version was exposed in 2014](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging)

You should avoid adding dependency on it directly in your projects. I assume the most of answers and the accepted one are not actual anylonger.

A preferrable way to use in your projects new alternatives, like `slf4j` or `log4j2`, which play the same role, as `jcl`. The reasons and motivation is another big topic, not for the scope of this issue.

If your application uses `log4j2`, and you meet the error, add dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
  <version>2.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

If you prefer `slf4j`, (already offered in previous comments/replies ) use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use Spring, most probably you have in the dependency tree:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and it solves the issue as well.

In the examples I skipped certain versions by purpose, they get deprecated very quickly, see [Offitial Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/).

In some cases you should not use  `version` attribute at all, preferring using dependencies from `BOM` files. Spring is an example.

Answer (score 1):

http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

use this url to download jar files and include them in your class path, issue will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the commons-logging.jar has been added to your libs and the classpath.. I had the same issue and that was because of this. 
dhammikas-

Answer (score 0):

I generally assign the classpath to a variable and then verify it.  I've written a small ruby script which I include in a my startup scripts which [validates the classpath before launching java](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Classpathchecker.rb).  Validating the classpath before the JVM starts has saved me lots of time troubleshooting these types of problems.

Comment: You should consider using tools like Maven instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was following the tutorial on tutorialpoint.com. Add after you complete **Step 2 - Install Apache Common Logging API:** You must **import external jar** libraries to the project from the files downloaded at this step. For me the file name was "**commons-logging-1.1.1**".

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on Android then note that apparently `java.beans` package is not complete on Android. To attempt to fix it on Android try the following:

1. Download [android-java-air-bridge.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidjavaairbridgejar.htm) (currently the download button is on the bottom of the page or [direct link here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-java/android-java-air-bridge.jar.zip))
2. Copy the downloaded jar to your *[APPROOT]/app/libs* directory (or link the jar in any other way)
3. Change the `import  ***` statements to that of air-bridge. Eg `import javadz.beanutils.BeanUtils` instead of `import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;`
4. Clean and rebuild the project

[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185068/3508719), [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408171/3508719)

I apologise as I realise this is not exactly answering the question, though this SO page comes up a lot when searching for android-generated `NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: beanUtils` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while the jar was present. No solution worked. What worked was deleting the jar from the file system (from .m2 directory) and then cleaning the maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in eclipse IDE, my solution was:
Right click in ***My project > Properties***

[image]

Click in **Maven** and write: ***jar*** in the **Active Maven Project**

[image]

Finally, Apply and Close

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was testing a Tomcat app in eclipse and got this error. I solved it by checking the `.classpath` file and corrected this entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

The  attribute `org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency` had been missing.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the jars are imported properly. I imported them using build path. But it didn't recognise the jar in WAR/lib folder. Later, I **copied the same jar to war/lib folder**. It works fine now. You can refresh / clean your project.

Answer (score -2):

Hello friends if your getting any not class found exception in hibernate code it is the problem of jar files.here mainly two problems
1.I mean to say your working old version of hibernate may be 3.2 bellow.So if u try above 3.6 it will works fine

2.first checkes database connection.if it database working properly their was a mistake in ur program or jar file.

please check these two prioblems if it also not working you tried to IDE . I am using netbeanside 6.9 version.here hibernate working fine.you dont get any error from class not founnd exception..

I hope this one helps more

Answer (score -2):

try adding this dependency
    
        org.apache.commons
        commons-exec
        1.3

Answer (score -3):

If all else fails, as it had for me, try putting the commons-logging-x.y.z.jar in your Tomcat lib directory.  It solved the problem!  BTW, I am using Tomcat 6.

Comment: name thing?  what are you talking about?

Answer (score -4):

Solution is to Add **common-logging.x.x** jar file