# Are there Android compatible alternatives to Property Utils?

Tags: android, apache-commons-beanutils

Is there a handy-dandy equivalent to `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils` on Android?

I can't seem to use bean `utils` in my android app due to some dependencies on `PropertyDescriptor`,and `IndexedPropertyDescriptor`. So I'm wondering if there are any alternatives?

Basically all I want to do is use a method name as a string "someMethod" and feed that into `setMethod(anObject, "someMethod", value)`, much like `PropertyUtils` does; but without having to resort to the nasties of reflection...

Or are my hands tied and I need to use Reflection?

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution to this problem? The answer below provides some info, but it'd be great to know if you found a full blown way of doing key/value coding on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibilty to use libraries or write own code depending on the `PropertyUtils`. But it sure isn't dandy. You can get the general idea about what has to be done in this [**thread**](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/38850).

There are apparently some projects who have successfully solved the issue, so you can study thier solution. Take a look at [**Drawingpad-base**](http://code.google.com/p/drawingpad-base/) and [**libgdx**](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). You can find `PropertyUtils` in the package `com.madrobot.beans` in the first project and `com.badlogic.gdx.beans` in the second.

Answer (score 10):

There is bridge library which works on Android: [android-java-air-bridge.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidjavaairbridgejar.htm). Just include into project path and use all apache **beanutils** features in your Android project as you could use in ordinary java application. Moreover, there are lot of other classes which moved to this Android supporting library. Look at the list.

Comment: this is the simple, compatible and working way should be marked as solution.