# Android line break in string from CSV

Tags: android, csv, line-breaks

I'm building an Android app, where I want to read data from a CSV file and display it in some Textviews. The last column can have a larger text with line breaks in it.

Example CSV row that I'm reading to a string array :

```
Cat1; Cat2; Sample Text\nwith a line break
```

After setting the string as the text of a textview, I will get this on the device/simulator:

> Sample Text\nwith a line break

If I set the string directly like this:

```
textView.setText("Sample Text\nwith a line break");
```

Or if I replace a different place holder like this:
( String in CSV: Sample Textzzzwith a line break )

```
textView.setText(someArray[2].replace("zzz", "\n"));
```

it will get me the desired result:

> Sample Text
> with a line break

I also tried .replace("\n", "\n") but this didn't help either.
What am I doing wrong? It's probably something basic.
I'm providing the CSV myself, so I could change something in there as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**
Thats how I read the CSV to a string array

```
int choosenfile = getResources().getIdentifier("test", "raw", getPackageName());
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(choosenfile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String line = "";
    try{
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(";", -1);
            someArray[0] = tokens[0];
            someArray[1] = tokens[1];
            someArray[2] = tokens[2];
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error" + line, e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Does your CSV file contain a \ character followed by an `n` character? You might need to edit the file to replace it with a newline, and be sure to quote it properly so the newline char doesn't start a new CSV row. Or do `.replace("\\n", "\n")` to replace the pair of characters with a newline char.

Comment: as in the example I have the \n between "Text" and "with".
Not sure on how or where to quote in the CSV.
I tried that one .replace("\\n", "\n") as well, didn't work.

Comment: `row that I'm reading to a string array ` You are nit showing how you read from the csv file so there is little we can do.

Comment: `Cat1; Cat2; Sample Text\nwith a line break` That is no valid content/line for a csv file. You should at least have `Cat1;Cat2;"Sample Text\nwith a line break"`.

Comment: @blackapps I added that part. And the quotes don't help either. It just gives me quotes on the output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a file `res/raw/data.csv` with the contents:

```
Cat1; Cat2; Sample Text\nwith a line break
```

And the following Java Code

```java
String[] someArray = new String[3];

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String line = "";
try{
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(";", -1);
        someArray[0] = tokens[0];
        someArray[1] = tokens[1];
        someArray[2] = tokens[2];
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error" + line, e1);
    e1.printStackTrace();
}


TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText(someArray[2].replace("\\n", "\n"));
```

It works as expected.

But you might want to consider the following to easily handle CSV files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055945/2232127

---

Also, your current loop will overwrite `someArray` on each iteration resulting in only containing the data of the last line in the file. Also make sure to close your streams when you're done using them.

Comment: I just copied the .replace part and now it works. I'm sure, I tried this several times by typing the two backslashes by hand. I don't know what went wrong there, but thanks.
Don't worry about the loop, originally it is a two dimensional array.