# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/beans/Introspector error

Tags: android, mockito, integration-testing, powermock

So I'm trying to write tests for an existing app, and I need to use `Mockito` and `PowerMock`, but I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljava/beans/Introspector;

I googled for a while and checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626317/how-to-use-powermock-on-android-sdk) which wasn't helpful and I really don't want to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065545/using-jars-that-use-java-beans-classes-introspector-beaninfo-or-propertydescri)

Here's part of my build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

// I had to comment this line, since it caused a different error
//    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.28.2"
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4'
    androidTestImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.0"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
}
```

As I mentioned before I get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/beans/Introspector;

Any help to resolve the issue or possible tutorials/blogs/links would be appreciated.

FYI: I get this error when I uncomment this line (`androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.28.2"`) in build.gradle:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest'

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` usually means you're missing a dependency.

Comment: hmmm, I can think of no dependency that would be missing. Although I don't know what dependency "Ljava/beans/Introspector" might belong to.

Comment: @e.y66 I know this is an old question, I have the same problem, how did you solve it (if you did) ?

Comment: There is an [open issue on Powermock for this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1062)