# I am not able to Run spring Application

Tags: spring

My console : Displaying following error please help me to resolve the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.<clinit>(CollectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.SimpleAliasRegistry.<init>(SimpleAliasRegistry.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.<init>(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.<init>(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
    at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: The question lacks a lot of information that should be provided: what are you trying to run and how? How did you build the software, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory)

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error text clearly explains, you need [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) in your classpath. Usually you do this by dropping a jar file to your lib directory or adding the correct dependency to your build file, but without more information the rest is just guessing.