# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-8, apache-commons-math

I'm developing a library (fpotencia) wich I use from a GUI program (fpotenciaui).
The library uses the `commons math` library.

When I run the GUI program I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex
    at fpotencia.Circuit.<init>(Circuit.java:101)
    at gui.MainGUI.<init>(MainGUI.java:34)
    at fpotenciaui.FPotenciaUI.main(FPotenciaUI.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

I have read in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java?rq=1) that this is due to the presence of the library at design time but not at run time.

I have also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory) that I need to include the library `commons-logging.jar` from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi), which I have done for both the libary and the UI projects.

I would like to be able to include whatever I need from Netbeans since when I share the code with others I do not want them to have to do things like including libraries in the path. I am electrical engineer and I find very messy having to do such things "manually", besides, why is Netbeans for if I have to include libraries in the path from the command line?

So my question is, why does Netbeans not sort this problem out if I am clearly including the library in the project?

PS: maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, if so, I'd appreciate some guidance to get this solved. Thanks.

Comment: The class that netbeans can't find is `org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex`. That's not a class of commons-logging. It's a class of commons-math. So it's commons-math that you need to add as a library of the project.

Comment: Yes, I have added it. It doesn't complain at build time but at run time.

Comment: I assume you build a jarfile? Is the lib contained in the jar file? In the manifest file in the jar there should be a reference to that lib. Is the reference there? How do you start your jar? Java -jar <jarfile.jar>? Give us some more info :)

Comment: So, how do you run the program?

Comment: Are you using ant or maven to build the project?

Comment: @Chris: It is a .jar file. I found out that the project that includes the library I'm making has to include the same dependencies that the library unlike a static library in C.

Comment: Ah. So the problem is fixed?

Comment: Yes Iĺl post the "Solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically I found out that (at least in Netbeans) when you create a library that has dependencies, those dependencies have to be included in whatever other project that you want to use the library you've made.