# Spring framework: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory ,despite adding commons-logging-1.2 jars in classpath

Tags: java, spring, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-logging

I am new to Spring framework.
I checked the following answer regarding the similar problem as i have :[Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory) 
But,i have tried all the solutions mentioned in that link,None worked.So,i request not to close this post/mark duplicate.

I have been using the the **JavaBrains Spring  youtube lectures** and running the same code as mentioned in the below lecture-4 link

> [YoutubeLinkForCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c6ZTF6cF88&index=4&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7)

Below is the **main class** as mentioned in above youtube lecture :

```
 package org.learningSpring;


import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class DrawingApp {

    Log logger =  LogFactory.getLog(DrawingApp.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
              ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/learningSpring/Spring.xml");


            Triangle triangle=(Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");

            triangle.draw();

            ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();

        }

    }
```

Rest of the code is same as in the link :[YoutubeLinkForCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c6ZTF6cF88&index=4&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7)

I am not using Maven for this & added all Jars manually.

Jars used in project :

- spring-framework-4.3.2.RELEASE-dist
- commons-logging-1.2 -
  downloaded from genuine resource [Website from where i downloaded the
  jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi)

**Below is the stack trace from exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:224)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.deen.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:14)
```

I debug and found that the code throws exception in AbstractApplicationContext.class at below line:

```
public AbstractApplicationContext() {
        this.logger = LogFactory.getLog(super.getClass()); //here
```

I made sure if there is **LogFactory.clas**s in **commons-logging-1.2 jars** and whether this class contains **getLog** method.

Below is my **.classpath** file.This contains the commons jar  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/CDC-1.1%Foundation-1.1"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Spring"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software/JAR/commons-logging-1.2-bin (2)/commons-logging-1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I read some answers on stackoverflow regarding this error and all they say is to add commons jar which i already added.

I have spent whole day trying to solve this error & feeling demoralised.I would be very much thankful if someone could help me to resolve this error.If you need any more detail then please let me know.

Comment: How you added the jar files? Are you using any IDE? You can place these lines in DrawingApp class, `Logger logger = LogFactory.getLog(DrawingApp.class)`, If you are getting compiler error in this line, then commons jar is not in the classpath of your application.

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE and yes,the code you mentioned compiles fine  :import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class DrawingApp {

 Logger logger = (Logger) LogFactory.getLog(DrawingApp.class);
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: Why you are importing import java.util.logging.Logger instead commons log  or logger?

Comment: For using commons logger, I have to change the code you mentioned to : Log logger =  LogFactory.getLog(DrawingApp.class); This compiles fine too.Still getting the same : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Comment: check the .classpath file of eclipse for commons jar.NoClassDefFoundError will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.

Comment: this is my .classpath file.This contains the common  jar : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/CDC-1.1%Foundation-1.1"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Spring"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software/JAR/commons-logging-1.2-bin (2)/commons-logging-1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>

Comment: If the answer proposed by our gentile moderator at the time of closing your question does not satisfy you, remember to check the **execution classpath**: When you click on "Run as...", check that the "classpath" tab has all the needed JARs.

Comment: @LittleSanti: big big thanks :D that was the issue.Despite adding jar in classpath and .classpath showing the jar is added ,i was getting exception.but with your advice, i tried "Run as ...then run configuration..added jar " and voila ! it worked :) no idea how ,but it worked :D

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You've been too much rushed at marking this question as duplicated, as it was not. The right answer is the one I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: @Naruto_Uzumaki You are welcome.