# why Struts has detected an unhandled exception?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have create a code to download pdf using struts 2. but when i run it it will throw exception...

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

File:   org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.java

Line number:    1,313

here is my code snapshot... where I face the exceptions ...

```
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    try {
        if (submit.equals("pdf")) {
            rs = new ReportDAO().getPdf();
            jasperPath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Reports");
            pdfName = "Studnet Report";
            rpt = "studentReport.jrxml";
   // I got error at this line....
            JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
            HashMap<String, Object> pm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String logo = jasperPath + "/ws.jpg";
            pm.put("logo", logo);
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperPath + "/" + rpt);
            System.out.println("ok");
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, pm, resultSetDataSource);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, jasperPath + pdfName + ".pdf");
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(jasperPath + pdfName + ".pdf"));

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "SUCCESS";

}
```

struts.xml

```
  <result name="SUCCESS" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${pdfName}.pdf"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
```

Exception:

**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

```
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.(JRLoader.java:67)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
```

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory**

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.(JRLoader.java:67)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory)

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this jar files.

[commons-logging library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)

then paste it in **WEB-INF/lib** on your Web content.

It says that your commons-logging library is not found.

hope it will helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you got the commons-logging library?

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.